# jpgraph - adjust the font-size of labels on the x-axis?

Tags: php, axis-labels, jpgraph

Does anyone know how to adjust the font-size of labels on the x-axis?  I looked through lots of manual pages and couldn't find anything close.

I tried

$graph->xaxis->scale->ticks->SetSize(8,3);

But actually couldn't get it to generate anything different.

I also have the graph_theme=null before I output the graph. If I remove it, it just changes the ticks on the y-axis and makes them more general.

```
$graph->graph_theme=null;
$graph->Stroke();
```

Comment: This apparently cannot be done.  Thanks for the down votes.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old topic but the following should work

```
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,14);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be done.  Also receiving down votes, not sure why, so closing this out and good luck to anyone who wants to do this, it doesn't appear possible.

Answer (score 0):

look this http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch14s08.html.

This line adjust the font-size of labels on the x-axis
$graph->xaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,9);

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It actually can be done, as Rebe said using `$graph->yaxis->SetFont(FF_ARIAL,FS_NORMAL,20);`

Just make sure, you are refering to the right axis and have the font in the fonts folder. In my case it was missing...and I had to upload the arial.ttf